# Athena query to find the size of directory in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a requirement to find the size of each directories in S3 bucket. I know that it is easily achievable through the get size option in the AWS S3 console but I have lot of directories to check and checking size of each directory manually seems to be tedious. I'm looking for some effective way to get the size through Athena

**I can export the S3 contents to the Athena table but is there any way to calculate the size of the contents through query ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) on your bucket, which will deliver a full listing of all objects in the bucket as a CSV, ORC or Parquet file, either daily or weekly (as you configure it, CSV is good if you want to look at the file in an editor or Excel, Parquet or ORC is great for Athena).

Follow the instructions in [Querying inventory with Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html#storage-inventory-athena-query) to run queries using Athena against the inventory.

S3 doesn't really have the concept "directory", so exactly how to run a query that calculates the size of each directory in a bucket depends on what you think of as a directory. A common convention is to think of a key like `a/b/c/d.txt` as a file `d.txt` in a directory `c`, in a directory `b`, in a directory `a`, but this is not how S3 sees things – to S3 there is just an object (file) with key `a/b/c/d.txt`. I'm going to assume it's this convention you're thinking about when you say "directory".

You can get the size of each leaf directory (e.g. `a/b/c`, but not `a/b` and `a`) with a query like this:

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace(key, '/[^/]+$') AS directory_prefix,
  SUM(size) AS directory_size
FROM my_inventory
GROUP BY 1
```

If you want the size of each directory regardless of hierarchies it becomes much more complicated, since there could be arbitrarily deep hierarchies (bounded by the max size of S3 keys, though), and it's not easy to craft a query that deals with that. Your best bet would be to run a query for the first level, another query for the second level, and so on until you know you don't have any deeper structures in your bucket.

---

A note on why it seems to be so easy to calculate directory sizes in the S3 console: what the console does is that it runs a `LIST` operation on the prefix you select (the "directory") and sums up the sizes of the objects it finds. This is quick and works well when there are just a couple of objects in a prefix. When there are hundreds of thousands it becomes *very* slow.

Comment: @Heisenberg if the answer solved your problem, mark it as the accepted answer. You can also upvote it if it was helpful.